# export video of dynamic graphics in complex manipulate interface

Tags: graphics, manipulate, export, video

I have a complex manipulate interface with many controls that draws a rather complex graphics (more specifically, several graphics composed and displayed in a TabView). How can I export a video of only the graphics (without the controls) when varying one specific slider? I experimented with different options but all are unsatisfactory so far. In general, when I export manipulate, the image quality is low, even when I increase resolution. I obtained the best visual results with a screen capture (using Quicktime on Mac), but this is not convenient, and also has the problem that the framerate is bad (the graphics renders rather slowly).

As a side remark, when I right click on the graphic and try to export it, the exported image shows errors (as in red regions, as if some commands couldn't execute)

Is there a way to just export the frames (for only the graphics) in screen quality to a file, while animating a specific slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options

1) Add the the following options to your `Manipulate`

```
Bookmarks->{"1":>{var1=valInitial, var2=val2,...},"2":>{var1=valFinal,var2=val2,...}}, 
InterpolationOrder->1
```

where `var1` is the name of the variable you wish to move between `valInitial` and `valFinal` and `var2,...` are the variables to hold constant.  If you add `"ControlAppearance"->None` in your `Export`, you'll get what you want.

2) Replace the `Manipulate` by `Table`, at least for the one variable you're interested in.  You'll need to do some fancy variable injection using `With`, and then you'll need to map `Setting` across the list to remove the controls.  Here is an example.  Notice how I'm initiallizing `a` to `aInit`, which is `1.5`.

```
Setting /@ Table[
   With[{aInit = 1.5, tMax = tm}, 
       Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a t], {t, 0, tMax}], {{a, aInit}, 1, 2}]
   ],
   {tm, 1, 10}
]
```

This is now a list of graphics which you can export to your hearts content.  I sometimes do this if I have a very complicate graphics and I want to do the export one frame at a time.

About your pinking in Export, that's probably a dynamic timeout during evaluation.  Write `Style[Manipulate[...],DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 60]` (or whatever number you wish to use, in seconds) to do the export.

Comment: Glad to read it. I have been wondering for a couple of days why there were red error boxes in some of the frames I exported from a Manipulate that ran in fact with no errors.

Comment: Part 1) of this answer looks puzzling. How is it used?

Comment: Because of this line in the documentation for QuickTime export: "If bookmarks are set in the Manipulate object, Export will create a QuickTime file by interpolating between the bookmarks while preserving the speed and duration of the Manipulate."

Comment: Thanky you! Now I understand it completely.